# FileOutputStream append on SD

Tags: android

I have a problem till now I can not understand.

`os = new FileOutputStream(file,doAppend);`

The file is on SD. If doAppend is false the file is saved correctly. If I split file in blocks and use first write with doAppend=false and successive with true the file is not saved correctly (as it is truncated).
The same function saves also to private folder on device but uses just `os = activity.openFileOutput(red.m_slika_ime, Context.MODE_PRIVATE+Context.MODE_APPEND);`

Between saving to SD or private the only difference is in OutputStream instantiation.

Since on private folder all works as expected it should be the FileOutputStream with append on Sd that is not working correctly.

Is this a known issue? workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Trying to understand correctly -the file gets truncated regardless of the doAppend variable?

Comment: Yes. I have about 3Kb picture that for testing I decided to split in chunks of 50 bytes. At the end I get 3 bytes. If I do not split in blocks the picture is complete.

Comment: I have alsto tried to add os.flush after each write, but no use.

Comment: I have also tried to use `new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,naKraj));`, again didn't help.

Comment: That was my next suggestion. Can you post the loop that splits and write the file? I can take a look in the morn if so.

Answer (score 0):

It was my stupid error. I was elsewhere, each time before writing to SD, erasing my own file.
Happens:)
Thanks Luke anyway